# how to implement math input in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to write math equation in React Native's TextInput and render what user typing. I found some math typesetting library for web. But for mobile, How can I achieve that?

User can easily write math equation with **custom keyboard** and can render in UI (I will katex for react native ).
I found most of the packages are for web platform.

But I got some ideas to use [react-native-keyboard-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-input) for my custom use. It is not okay what I expected. Is there anyone who experienced it?

Thanks.